# C - Warning [pe069] integer conversion resulted in truncation

Tags: c, hex, warnings, iar, firmware

I know that this question has been asked several times, anyway I didn't find and answer to my specific case:

IAR Embedded Workbench returs this warning on compiling:

"Warning [pe069] integer conversion resulted in truncation" on the line:

```
SPI2_Tx(DVC_CTR2,       0x1000);
```

where DVC_CTR2 is

```
#define DVC_CTR2                0x0F
```

and SPI2_Tx definition is

```
static void SPI2_Tx(uint8_t pAddress, uint8_t pData)
```

How can I resolve this warning?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `0x1000` doesn't fit into an `uint8_t` that's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning : 'integer conversion results in truncation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479403/warning-integer-conversion-results-in-truncation)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you, so I should go for uint16_t right?

Comment: SPI2_Tx is your function or from a library?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani SPI2_Tx is a function of mine, anyway I SOLVED! As 
Jean-FrançoisFabre said, I just had to change "uint8_t pData" to "uint16_t pData"

Comment: Transmitting something over SPI in two chunks might have side effects...it boils down to what the device datasheet says and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you cannot transmit a two-byte value through SPI routine that transmits a single byte.

You should be able to do it with two separate calls:

```
SPI2_Tx(DVC_CTR2, 0x10);
SPI2_Tx(DVC_CTR2, 0x00);
```

If you must transmit 16 bits at once, look up a different routine that takes `uint16_t`.

Comment: that is, of course, if the data is a sequence of bytes. Else, if it depends on endianness, the order of sends must be reversed if little endian